Trouble saving workout data to database using Entity Framework Core and ASP.NET Web API
I'm encountering difficulties when attempting to save workout data to a database using Entity Framework Core and ASP.NET Web API. I have a Workout class defined with properties such as WorkoutId, ExerciseTypeGroups, CreatorId, Creator and Status. The ExerciseTypeGroups property is a list of ExerciseTypeGroup objects.
I have implemented a CreateAsync method in my dbContext to add the Workout object to the database and save changes using SaveChangesAsync. Additionally, I have a WorkoutManager.CreateAsync method that serializes the Workout object to JSON and sends it to a server endpoint using HTTP POST request.
Here's a summary of the key components:
//The command initializing the data entering
public ICommand CompleteWorkoutCommand => new Command(CompleteWorkout);

private async void CompleteWorkout()
{
     Workout workout = new Workout();
     workout.ExerciseTypeGroups = new List<ExerciseTypeGroup>(ExerciseTypeGroups);
     string userIdString = Preferences.Get("UserID", defaultValue: null);

     if (int.TryParse(userIdString, out int userId))
     {
         // If parsing was successful, set the CreatorId property
         workout.CreatorId = userId;
         workout.Creator = await UserManaging.ReadAsync(userId);

         // Create the workout asynchronously
         Task.Run(() => WorkoutManager.CreateAsync(workout)).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
     }
     else
     {
         // Handle the case where parsing fails
         Console.WriteLine("Failed to parse user ID from preferences.");
         // You might want to handle this error case appropriately for your application
     }
}

// DbContext method to add Workout object to the database
public async Task CreateAsync(Workout item)
{
    try
    {
        dbContext.Workouts.Add(item);
        await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Handle exception
        throw;
    }
}

// Workout class definition
public class Workout
{
    [Key]
    public int WorkoutId { get; set; }
    public List<ExerciseTypeGroup> ExerciseTypeGroups { get; set; }
    public int CreatorId { get; set; }
    public User Creator { get; set; }
    public Status Status { get; set; }

    public Workout()
    {
        ExerciseTypeGroups = new List<ExerciseTypeGroup>();
    }

    public Workout(User user)
    {
        Status = Status.Waiting;
        Creator = user;
        ExerciseTypeGroups = new List<ExerciseTypeGroup>();
    }
}

// Manager method to send Workout object to server endpoint
public static async Task CreateAsync(Workout item)
{
    try
    {
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item);
        var data = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        var response = await Client._httpClient.PostAsync(Client._url + $"Workout", data);
    }
    catch (HttpRequestException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Request error: {e.Message}");
    }
}

// Server-side endpoint in ASP.NET Web API controller
[HttpPost]
public async Task Create([FromBody]Workout item)
{
    await _workoutContext.CreateAsync(item);
}

Despite implementing these methods, I'm encountering issues where the workout data is not being saved to the database. I have verified that both client-side and server-side code are being executed without errors, but the data is not persisted in the database.
What could be the possible reasons for this issue, and how can I troubleshoot and resolve it? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. If there is not enough information here is my github https://github.com/danchuu/Muscles_AppDR. Thank you.

Remove your catch (Exception ex) because it doesn't do anything useful. What do you see in your debugger? Add SQL logging so you can see the actual SQL being generated. Use your RDBMS' Tracing or Profiler tools to see what's happening. Are you connecting to the right database instance? Are you using MSSQL, MySQL/MariaDb, Postgres? Etc?

@Dai I added the SQL logging and here is the fail https://pastebin.com/sCh3pnBi

The errors reported in that script do not correspond to the error in your post.

@Dai Do you mean the error is somewhere else

...at risk of sounding callous, it sounds like you need to learn how to use your debugger.

First, there is an exception, so the statement "server-side code is being executed without errors" is not true. Second, take a look at official EF Core documentation how to work with disconnected objects. public User Creator { get; set; } is causing the issue in this specific case since dbContext.Add will mark the object and all related objects for creation. But in your case the User is not new. There are ways to resolve it, none of them universal. In general, either don't send Creator object, just CreatorId, or Attach the Creator before calling Add .

@dancho Your approach is completely wrong. First try to learn how to use EF Core properly https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/entity-framework-core.aspx

@DarkkL can you elabourate

@IvanStoev I will look into that but I dont think its my current problem. I tried to use only CreatorID but it didnt work out. Do you have any other idea

The problem was that i was giving null to a non nulable column in the database.
